# How do I match up text labels in a legend created in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am building a data visualization project utilizing the d3 library. I have created a legend and am trying to match up text labels with that legend.

To elaborate further, I have 10 rect objects created and colored per each line of my graph. I want text to appear adjacent to each rect object corresponding with the line's color.

**My Problem**

-Right now, an array containing all words that correspond to each line appears adjacent to the top rect object. And that's it.

I think it could be because I grouped my data using the d3.nest function. Also, I noticed only one text element is created in the HTML. Can anyone take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

JS Code

```
const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 0 },
  width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;
height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// maybe a translate line

// document.body.append(svg);
const div_block = document.getElementById("main-div");
// console.log(div_block);

const svg = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) // viewport size
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom) // viewport size
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(40, 20)"); // center g in svg

// load csv

d3.csv("breitbartData.csv").then((data) => {
  // convert Count column values to numbers
  data.forEach((d) => {
    d.Count = +d.Count;
    d.Date = new Date(d.Date);
  });
  // group the data with the word as the key
  const words = d3
    .nest()
    .key(function (d) {
      return d.Word;
    })
    .entries(data);

  // create x scale

  const x = d3
    .scaleTime() // creaters linear scale for time
    .domain(
      d3.extent(
        data,

        // d3.extent returns [min, max]
        (d) => d.Date
      )
    )
    .range([margin.left - -30, width - margin.right]);

  // x axis

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .style("transform", `translate(-3px, 522px)`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label-x")
    .attr("x", "55%")
    .attr("dy", "4em")
    // .attr("dy", "20%")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text("Months");

  // create y scale

  const y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.Count)])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

  // y axis

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .style("transform", `translate(27px, 0px)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // line colors

  const line_colors = words.map(function (d) {
    return d.key; // list of words
  });

  const color = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(line_colors)
    .range([
      "#e41a1c",
      "#377eb8",
      "#4daf4a",
      "#984ea3",
      "#ff7f00",
      "#ffff33",
      "#a65628",
      "#f781bf",
      "#999999",
      "#872ff8",
    ]); //https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaleordinal

  // craete legend variable
  const legend = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("transform", "translate(-20, 50)");

  // create legend shapes and locations

  legend
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(words)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", width + 65)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return i * 20;
    })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return color(d.key);
    });

  // create legend labels

  legend
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", width + 85)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return i * 20 + 9;
    })
    // .attr("dy", "0.32em")
    .text(
      words.map(function (d, i) {
        return d.key; // list of words
      })
    );
  // returning an array as text
  // });

  svg
    .selectAll(".line")
    .data(words)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", function (d) {
      return color(d.key);
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", function (d) {
      return d3
        .line()
        .x(function (d) {
          return x(d.Date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
          return y(d.Count);
        })(d.values);
    });
});
```

**Image of the problem:**
[image]

P.S. I cannot add a JSfiddle because I am hosting this page on a web server, as that is the only way chrome can read in my CSV containing the data.

**My Temporary Solution**

```
  function leg_labels() {
    let the_word = "";
    let num = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      the_word = words[i].key;
      num += 50;

      d3.selectAll(".legend")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", width + 85)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
          return i + num;
        })
        // .attr("dy", "0.32em")
        .text(the_word);
    }
  }

  leg_labels();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Your problem has to do with this code

```
legend
.append("text")
.attr("x", width + 85)
.attr("y", function (d, i) {
  return i * 20 + 9;
})
// .attr("dy", "0.32em")
.text(
  words.map(function (d, i) {
    return d.key; // list of words
  })
);
```

You are appending only a single *text* element and in the text function you are returning the complete array of words, which is why all words are shown.

**Solution**

Create a corresponding text element for each legend rectangle and provide the correct word. There are multiple ways to go about it.

You could use *foreignObject* to append HTML inside your SVG, which is very helpful for text, but for single words, plain SVG might be enough.

I advise to use a *g* element for each legend item. This makes positioning a lot easier, as you only need to position the rectangle and text relative to the group, not to the whole chart.

Here is my example:

```
let legendGroups = legend
.selectAll("g.legend-item")
.data(words)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "legend-item")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
  return `translate(${width + 65}px, ${i * 20}px)`;
});

legendGroups
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 10)
.attr("height", 10)
.style("fill", function (d) {
  return color(d.key);
});


legendGroups 
.append("text")
.attr("x", 20)
.attr("y", 9)
.text(function(d, i) { return words[i].key; });
```

This should work as expected.
Please note the use of groups for easier positioning.

Comment: Thanks! I will be implementing your solution. I created my own solution which I edited into my first question above. However my new solution just creates a text element for each word, and the placement is odd.

Comment: Also, could you explain the significance of the $ signs? I know they are using in jQuery, but I am still relatively new to JS. Thanks!

Comment: Your temporary solution iterates with a loop over all words and selects the main g element with class legend. This element exists only once, so that everu iteration you add a new text element, but the index is always 0, because there is onky a single index, so the y positioning wilk not work. You shoukd use _.data_ function to map the words to corresponding elements, like I did. Using loops to append multiple elements with d3.js is bad practice, because that the selections and _.data_ are for.

Comment: You can use my solution as is and replace it with your legend code. The $ signs have nothing to do with jquery. They are part of javascript's string interpolation syntax. It is for building strings. _g_ elements need to be positioned through the transform. Search for "js string interpolation" and you will understand.

Comment: Hey thanks. I researched string interpolation and template literals last night. For some reason I am receiving a missing ")" error on the attribute transform line in the 'let legendGroups' variable, although this this code is completely identical to what you provided me. Any ideas? I am also troubleshooting on my own but I can't find any reason for this bug.

Comment: Great, that you researched it. The code I provided has proper syntax without missing brackets, so I cannot help you with that. Maybe you have a single open bracket somewhere else in your code, which gets the interpreter confused.

Comment: Aha! found the bug. turns out if I add that transform attribute on const legendGroups to be .style("transform, ...) instead of .attr("transform", ...) it works. I guess .style and .attr have different behaviours.

Comment: _style_ adds a css style, while _attr_ adds an html attribute. _attr_ should be correct here, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform ; though most latest browsers also support similar css styles on svg elements (Except of course ie 11).